# Owncloud: Problems after change theme

Tags: php, html, templates, owncloud

I'm have a owncloud running and edited the theme yesterday. Everything worked fine, but now I get this when I open up the cloud:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><html class="ng-csp ie ie8 lte9 lte8" data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="de_DE" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ng-csp ie ie9 lte9" data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="de_DE" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="ng-csp" data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="de_DE" ><!--<![endif]-->
    <head data-requesttoken="W1IvBx1AX1duRBttEDcfHVMbMwMCNAcldBEbYA4Q:i+a7ir6365z7SM4x1cUKZWsA1pNOIE">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
        ownCloud        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="referrer" content="never">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=543672169">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#1d2d44">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><html class="ng-csp ie ie8 lte9 lte8" data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="de_DE" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ng-csp ie ie9 lte9" data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="de_DE" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="ng-csp" data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="de_DE" ><!--<![endif]-->
    <head data-requesttoken="">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
        ownCloud        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="referrer" content="never">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=543672169">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#1d2d44">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
More details can be found in the server log.
```

I'd only changed the core/templates/layout.guest.php & layout.user.php.
Already did a rollback and tried other files from the web, but nothing worked, can anyone help me on this?